# escaping URL request? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, escaping

I have a request to a page that looks like /doSomthing?a=that&ret=url
however now i need to login so i must do something like /login?ret=/doSomthing?a=that&ret=url
This doesnt work as well as one may hope so how do i correctly escape the return URL then unescape it?

I am using ASP.NET with C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should URL encode the querystring part, which can be done using the [UrlEncode method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) of the HttpUtility class:

```
 HttpUtility.UrlEncode(yourString);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by passing the target url through the [`UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode.aspx) method in the HttpServerUtility class. Example use, within a Page class:

```
string urlEncoded = Server.UrlEncode(this.Request.RawUrl);
```